# MySQL select columns by number .e.g. first 3 columns of table x

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to avoid using `SELECT ALL` `*` but i dont want to specify names instead i want to specify column number in select clause e.g.

```
SELECT column(1,3,8) FROM my_table
```

Is there working way to do this with one query?

Right now only way i see is run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_table` but then how i make this into one query?

Comment: That is generally a horrible, horrible idea; you're trying to save yourself less than a minute of typing at the cost of having to look back and forth between your query and your schema constantly, and pushing that cost on to anyone down the line that has to look at such queries when they inevitably break. _(MySQL has let queries `ORDER BY` the "column numbers" of the fields in the SELECT for a long time, but they have finally realized even that was a rather ridiculous thing to do and deprecated the feature.)_ (FYI, "officially" columns do not have an order.)

Comment: It would have been better than `SELECT *` AFAIK they deprecated `GROUP BY` while `ORDER BY` still has green light http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html Could you provide some reference for _"officially" columns do not have an order._?

Comment: Anything is better than `SELECT *` ;)  I'm not sure what you are trying to say with the reference to that manual page about optimization, the page for [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) explicitly states _"Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard"_ when talking about `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`, without giving an exception for either.

Comment: Oh, as far as a reference on the columns not "officially" having an order, it is just something I remember from early in the first the RDBMS course I took; I still have to resist using the term "tuple" when referring to rows/records. I probably could've picked a better term for what I was trying to say than "officially", it is more of a "data theory" concept I am trying to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [SELECT page of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) makes no mention of any such capability.

Answer (score 0):

Could do it with two queries. The first query would be

```
show columns from table_name
```

Then you can use the results of that query to determine the columns to select.

Comment: This is the same as `describe table_name` or `desc table_name`